# Decoding string in Java returned from AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am returning Data from my AWS account using

```
        GetRoleRequest getRoleRequest = GetRoleRequest.builder().roleName("ec2_role_powered").build();
    GetRoleResponse listRoles = iam.getRole(getRoleRequest);
    Role role = listRoles.role();
    String service = role.assumeRolePolicyDocument();
    System.out.println(service);
```

It is returning `role.assumeRolePolicyDocument();` in the following format:

> %7B%22Version%22%3A%222012-10-17%22%2C%22Statement%22%3A%5B%7B%22Effect%22%3A%22Allow%22%2C%22Principal%22%3A%7B%22Service%22%3A%22ec2.amazonaws.com%22%7D%2C%22Action%22%3A%22sts%3AAssumeRole%22%7D%5D%7D

While it is supposed to be in JSON format or something as it is like this in AWS CloudShell console:

[image: enter code here]

How am I supposed to get a string like shown in the picture or decode the %7B like characters to their original format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string `"%7B%22Version%22%3A%222012-10-17%22%2C%22Statement%22%3A%5B%7B%22Effect%22%3A%22Allow%22%2C%22Principal%22%3A%7B%22Service%22%3A%22ec2.amazonaws.com%22%7D%2C%22Action%22%3A%22sts%3AAssumeRole%22%7D%5D%7D"` is url encoding.

```java
String service = role.assumeRolePolicyDocument();
System.out.println(java.net.URLDecoder.decode(service, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```